# angularjs ui-router animated scroll to anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have just found that I can navigate to anchor points using ui-router by setting up my links like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home({ '#': 'creative' })">creative</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="home({ '#': 'work' })">work</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="home({ '#': 'contact' })">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

While this is great, I would like to animate to the anchor position. I figured I could use one of the state events, so I tried this:

```
$transitions.onFinish({ to: true }, function () {

    console.log('the state has changed');

    console.log($location.hash());
    var hash = $location.hash();

    if (hash) {
        var target = document.querySelector('#' + hash);

        console.log(target);

        var element = angular.element(target);

        console.log(element);

        $document.scrollToElement(element, 0, 2000);
    } else {

        // Scroll to the top of the page
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
});
```

But the view hasn't loaded yet, so the element is not anywhere to find.
If there a way of animating my scrollTo?

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to add this animation in proper moment. Proper moment will be when your view will be loaded and compiled. How can we be 100% sure that view is loaded and compiled? Add a directive to the view!

When view will be ready, directive will be initialized and you can bind your animation to the element. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Vitalii was right, creating a directive was the way to go.
I simply did this:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('autoscroll', directive);

function directive($document, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var offset = attrs.offset || 0;
            var duration = attrs.duration || 2000;              

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return $location.hash();
            }, function (hash) {
                if (hash) {
                    var anchor = document.querySelector('#' + hash);
                    var target = angular.element(anchor);
                    $document.scrollToElement(target, offset, duration);
                } else {
                    // Scroll to the top of the page if no hash has been supplied
                    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
                }
            });
        }

    };
};
```

And used this on the actual view template file (with the target ids) and it worked.